# Username in azure b2c user flow

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I want to capture the username of the user during registration using user flow. I couldn't find that in attributes and even didn't find the azure user profile list. I am getting username attribute in login id token but that is coming as empty. I want to understand how azure b2c captures username of user and is there any capability to take unique username during registration using user flow

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes#azure-ad-user-resource-type

I tried to create custom attribute for username but sadly we can add validation using user flow, want to understand how to use build in username

Comment: It looks like the answer is in the linked page you referenced. I just ran a sample user flow using username and what I entered for username shows up in the UserPrincipalName field. According to the table - this is not available in User Flows, only Custom Policies. (Although it also says this attribute is not available in the Azure Portal and I can see it there.) I assume MS wants you to link to the Object Id in the "sub" claim instead of to a username that could change.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use custom policies, have a look at the samples e.g. this one for [username](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-signup-or-signin).

Comment: Thank you @rbrayb for sharing this but I am not looking for custom policy but looking for user flow with username not as sign in identifier

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the local account identity provider as User ID signup in the SignUp/SignIn user flow by navigating to Identity providers which will allow to SignUp during registration with the username and password.
[image]

[image]

In the users, you can see account has been created with username with signIn type userName.

[image]

This userName can be used to Signin to your application.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-local?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Comment: I am getting email signup option only